# Error: (0, _react.createContext) is not a function when removing 'use client' directive in Next.js application

Tags: webpack, continuous-integration, server-side-rendering, netlify, next.js13

I am encountering an error in my Next.js application when trying to remove the 'use client' directive from one of my components. The application works fine on my local server with the 'use client' directive, but when I remove it, I get the following error:

"Unhandled Runtime Error: Error: (0, _react.createContext) is not a function"

I have tried deploying the application to Netlify by pushing it to a GitHub repository, but it fails to build due to the same error.

I have already checked my import statements and ensured that I am importing from the 'react' package correctly. I also made sure my Next.js and React versions are up to date. However, the error still persists.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the removal of the 'use client' directive, as the error occurs only when I remove it. I would like to know why this error is happening and how I can resolve it while still being able to deploy my application on Netlify.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!